# Flash AS3: Dynamic Sound sampling rate not 44100hz?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, dynamic

[Adobe's Dynamic Audio generation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html) states that dynamic audio is sampled at 44100 hz. I am using a dynamic audio generation library and setting its output sample rate to 44100 hz, and when fed into the `Sound` it is much slower than it should be.

I can change the sample rate output by the library, making the sound play at the correct speed, but it decreases audio quality, making it 22050 hz essentially. This is odd since Adobe claims it's sampled at 44khz, not 22khz.

What should I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the library I was using outputs stereo sound, one sample for left, and one sample for right. In my AS3, I was erroneously writing each sample twice (to both left and right) since I expected the library's output to be monaural.

Removed the extra write call and things are working well.